# $x^2 + 4xy = 10^{100}$ how many solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x^2 + 4xy = 10^{100}$ how many integer solutions there?

Can't find the answer, because there is too big number. Help me please

I know, how to solve it if I have 100 instead of $10^{100}$: 100 is $2^2$ and $5^2$, so I will try to solve like x = 2, x + 4y = $2*5^2$, then x = $2^2$, x + 4y = $5^2$ etc. But because 10^100 is too big, it will take a lot of time to iterate, so here is my problem

I tried to find it like sum of arithmetic progression (because if we have $10^{11}$ instead of $10^{100}$ there will be 192 solutions, $10^{12}$ => 234 solutions and $10^{13}$ => 280.) So $a_1 = -2, d = 4$, but number of solutions is too big and it can't be true.

I think there are the way to solve it easily

Comment: Do you mean integer solution?

Comment: If you are talking solutions that are integers, if you move everything to one side, this becomes $x^2+4xy-10^{100}=0.$ We see this is a quadratic, meaning that it has $\boxed{2}$ integer solutions. :)

Comment: @Bongocat That's not right; the coefficients aren't constants.

Comment: How would you do it if the constant were $100$ instead of $10^{100}$?

Comment: @jobseeker_68141 yes

Comment: @saulspatz 100 is 2^2 and 5^2, so I will try to solve like x = 2, x + 4y = 2*5^2, then x = 2*2, x + 4y = 5^2 etc
But because 10^100 is too big, it will take a lot of time to iterate, so here is my problem

Comment: You really should put all that in your question.  You wouldn't have gotten all those downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: $x^2+4xy=10^{100}\implies (x + 2 y)^2 - (2y)^2=10^{100}$. Equation  $x^2 - y^2=10^{100}$ has 19998 solutions, equation $(x + 2 y)^2 - (2y)^2=10^{100}$ has 19594 solutions. This can calculate in pari/gp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea. $x(x+4y)=10^{100}$, so $x$ must be a factor of $10^{100}$.  The factors of $10^{100}$ are all of the form $2^a5^b$, where $0\leq a,b\leq100$.  That gives $101^2$ factors, but not every one of them will work as $x$.  We also need to be able to solve $2^a5^b(2^a5^b+4y)=10^{100}$ where $y$ is an integer (not necessarily positive.)

How does this restrict the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Now we have $2^{2a}5^{2b} + 2^{2+a}5^{b}y$, the lower edge still can be 0, because we have $4y = 10^100$, but I have no idea about the higher :(

We need integer y, so y = $\frac{2^{100}5^{100} - 2^{2a}5^{2b}}{2^{a+2}5^{b}}$ = $\frac{2^{100}5^{100}}{2^{a + 2}5^{100}}$ - $2^{a-2}5^{b}}$ => $\frac{2^{100}5^{100}}{2^{a + 2}5^{100}}$ must be integer, => a ≤ 98, b ≤ 100 ?

Comment: My fault, we can't have $a$ less, than 2. So 2 ≤ a ≤ 98, 0 ≤ b ≤ 100 ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: but if you will try to prove it by wolfram (eg $10^{12}$ instead $10^{100}$), you will get 234 solutions, but as we have 2 ≤ $a$ ≤ 10, 0 ≤ $b$ ≤ 12, which give us 9*13  = 117. Looks like we need to multiply by 2 our answer. Is it because of 
commutativity?

Comment: @xufana You need to multiply by $2$ because if (x,y) is a solution then so is $(-x,-y)$